# Can’t login to wp-admin after changing site’s url

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

After changing wordpress link from my website dashboard.i can't loging anymore from the new of old link.
After looking on some youtube videos. i got some instructions to change site url from my php admin.
But i can't find this sitre url.

someone can help me?

i've tried to change it from my php admin. but site url is missing.
i'm working from online hosting wordpress

Answer (score 0):

You have to access with phpMyadmin the table 'wp_options', there you will find the 'site url' and 'home'.
Access your database using through your webhosting service provider.

Comment: I've tried this way but i don't have site url or home.